# Proving language from Hamming Distance is regular

Tags: automata, regular-language

The Hamming distance $H(x, y)$ between two bit
strings x and y is the number of places at which they differ. For example, $H(011, 110) = 2$.
(If $|x| \not= |y|$, then their Hamming distance is infinite.)

Given a language $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$, we write $N_k(A)$ to denote the set of strings at distance less than or equal $k$ from $A$, that is,
$$N_K(A) = \{x \in \{0,1\}^*\;|\;\exists y(y \in A \text{ and }H(x,y) \leq k)\}$$

Prove that if a language $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$ is regular, then so is $N_2(A)$.

This problem is adapted from Automata and Computability by Dexter C. Kozen p302.

How would this be proven?

Comment: Sketch: Construct an NFA with four copies of the machine for $A$: the states are $A\times\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ where the second component counts how many of the input symbols were wrong. If $A$ has transition $p\to^s q$, then the modified $A$ will have $\langle p, e\rangle\to^s\langle q, e\rangle$, for when $s$ is the expected symbol, and also $\langle p, e\rangle \to^{\bar s}\langle q, e+1\rangle$ for when $s$ is the wrong symbol.  All the accepting states are as usual in the first three copies of $A$, but all of the $\langle p, 3\rangle$ states reject because too many errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\def\cA{\mathcal{A}}
$$
Let $L$ be a regular language on the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$. Since $N_2(L) = N_1(N_1(L))$, it suffices to prove that $N_1(L)$ is regular.
Let $\cA = (Q, A, \cdot, i, F)$ be the minimal automaton of $L$. For each state $p$, $q$ of $\cA$, let $L_{p, q}$ be the language accepted by $\cA$ with $p$ as initial state and $S$ as set of final states. I let you verify that
$$
N_1(L) = L \cup \bigcup_{(p,q) \mid p \cdot 0 = q}L_{i,\{p\}}1 L_{q,F} 
\cup \bigcup_{(p,q) \mid p \cdot 1 = q}L_{i,p}0 L_{q,F}
$$
It follows that $N_1(L)$ is regular.